# Cordova 6.5.0. Failed to build android apps after updating android studio to 2.3.1 and SDK tools

Tags: cordova, sdk, android-studio-2.3, phonegap

I am working on three different phonegap projects, I was able to build to android platform until I did the biggest thing I regret for it "UPDATE"

Previously I was able to use command `phonegap build android` or `cordova build android`, and the build was successful with no errors

But after update I found the first problem :

```
Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

Although, Android_home was set before, but I ensured it again. then I tried to build but failed for same error. Later I found solution on this thread [Installing-Android-SDK-Tools](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Installing-Android-SDK-Tools)

I downloaded tools_`r25.2.3-windows.zip` and extracted contents to sdk folder, then problem (ANDROID_HOME not found) Solved!!

After that I tried to `phonegap build android`, then I got this error

```
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"D:\myProject\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\myProject\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

I got mad, even I tried to create new project `phonegap create myApp` and moved content of `www` folder and `config.xml`, then `phonegap build android`, but no luck Failed again for same reason mentioned above